# how to focus on an input in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

This should be simple but I can't find a solution, the closest answer i can find on SO is this: [How do I programmatically set focus to dynamically created FormControl in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190075/how-do-i-programmatically-set-focus-to-dynamically-created-formcontrol-in-angula)

However this is way more convoluted that my requirements. Mine are simple. I have an input in the template like so:

```
<div *ngIf="someValue">    
    <input class="form-control" #swiper formControlName="swipe" placeholder="Swipe">
</div>
```

(Note, it's in an ngx-boostrap form-control group but I'm pretty sure this should not matter)

And I have a button that when clicked calls the following function:

```
onClick() {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.swiper.nativeElement, 'focus')
}
```

The goal is that when the button is clicked, my input element gets focus.  here is the rest of my component (the relevant parts):

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChildren, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from wherever/my/service/is

export class MyClass {
    @ViewChildren('swiper') input: ElementRef;
    someValue: any = false;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer, service: MyService) {
       this.service.getSomeData().subscribe(data => {
          this.someValue = true;
       }
    }

    onClick() {
        this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.swiper.nativeElement, 'focus');
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
at RendererAdapter.invokeElementMethod (core.js:12032)
etc...
```

Any ideas?

(Angular 5 btw)

Note, I edited the code to more accurately reflect what is actually going on, I think there may be some synchronization issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using `ViewChildren` which returns a `QueryList` You need to use `ViewChild` and your code should work.

```js
export class MyClass {
    @ViewChild('swiper') swiper: ElementRef;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

    onClick() {
        this.swiper.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: so I changed it to ViewChild and it still doesn't work.  Also put in a console log right at the beginning of my onClick function to see what the value of 'this.swiper' was and saw that it was undefined so i think my ViewChild is not set up correctly.  not sure

Comment: note, there is more to this template but i didn't think it was relevant. now i do.  One of the issues is possibly that i have a conditional *ngIf on one of the parent elements so the whole thing isn't displayed till i get some data from the back end.  could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes that is most likely the reason that it is undefined. I also noticed that you named the swiper `input` but reference `swiper` in the `OnClick` method. Update that and see if it works.

Comment: I figured it out.  you gave me half of what i needed.  i'll post an answer to explain...

Comment: i got error @ViewChild() error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. solved by adding {static:false} ie: `@ViewChild('swiper', {static: false}) swiper: ElementRef;`

Answer (score 9):

This is how I solved it:

Template:

```
<input class="form-control" #swiper formControlName="swipe" placeholder="Swipe">
```

Component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class MyClass {
    @ViewChild('swiper') swiper: ElementRef;

    constructor() {}

    onClick() {
        this.swiper.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
```

The key being two things: first using the ViewChild not ViewChildren (thanks @Teddy Stern for that one) and second there is no need to use the Renderer at all, just directly use the nativeElement's focus function.

Answer (score 3):

if you have a input and a button

```
<input #myinput>
<button (click)="myinput.focus()">click</button>
```

Comment: Also correct, and simpler.  In my actual scenario i also needed to do other things in the function that was called besides just focusing on the input.

Comment: Clean and simple :)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested, to focus on an element which is generated dynamically, `#name` is not possible to keep in the field as attribute. I found a work around using native JS.

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="update.newComment"
          [name]="'update-' + index" 
          placeholder="comment"></textarea>
```

Now, a trigger to focus on above `textarea` could be like

```
<span (click)="focusOn(index);">Comment</span>
```

Click event will be handled in ts as

```
focusOn(fieldName) {
    const commmentBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(`textarea[ng-reflect-name="update-${fieldName}"]`);
    for( let i in commmentBoxes) {
        const element: any = commmentBoxes[i];
        const attributs = element.attributes;
        for(let j in attributs) {
            const attribute = attributs[j];
            if (attribute.nodeName === 'ng-reflect-name' && attribute.nodeValue === `update-${fieldName}`) {
                element.focus();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `cdkFocusInitial` directive works for me:

```html
<input
    matInput
    cdkFocusInitial />
```

Comment: I spent about 3 hours scouring stackoverflow, google, blogs, etc., tried at least 10 approaches, and this was the only answer that worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

And sometimes you can use attribute `autofocus` in html...