# Set focus on Child component textbox from Parent component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to set focus on a child component textbox from Parent component in Angular.

**Parent Component HTML**:

```
<button (click)="setFocusOnChildComponentTextBox()">Button</button>
<child-component></child-component>
```

**Child Component HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt"></input>
```

**Parent Component TS**:

```
setFocusOnChildComponentTextBox() {
// write code to set focus on child-component "txt" textbox
}
```

The above is just a sample code I am trying to achieve.

Normally in Angular we can pass input properties to child component and have output methods. In this case, I need to call a method of child component from the parent component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to focus on an input in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927624/how-to-focus-on-an-input-in-angular)

Comment: Thanks Richard. It partially answers the question but I want to know how to access the child component from parent component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In child component lets say you have input

```
<input type="text" #myInput></input>
```

In child component typescript have

```
@ViewChild('myInput', {read:ElementRef}) myInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
```

In parent component typescript have

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) comp: ChildComponent;
```

to focus use

```
this.comp.myInput.nativeElement.focus();
```

Comment: I have a similar situation but I am using the <child-component> twice in my template and am getting the error "Found 2 elements with non-unique id ".    any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: use viewchildren to get both inputs in array, if want them separately, give a different name like #myInputTwo